# Blank White icon in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, icons

Many of the icons in my Win 8.1 have become blank! I followed the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635447/en-us), but nothing changed. I also did `sfc /scannow`, and everything was ok. How can I resolve the problem?

Edit: I guess my issue is due to uninstalling ObjectDesktop. It might have removed an important DLL

Comment: [How to clear the icons cache in Windows 8 or 8.1](https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-icons-cache/?PageSpeed=noscript#How_to_clear_the_icons_cache_in_Windows_8_or_81)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks! but It did not help. I guess my issue is due to uninstalling ObjectDesktop. It might remove an important DLL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this important information ;)

Comment: Clearing the iconcache*.db files was not possible due to the 'File In Use' scenario. Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted ObjectDesktop, and got this solution:

Access your System Registry (XP - Start-> Run, Vista/7/8 - WinKey +R) and in the run box type regedit. Then go to the following Key;

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\IconHandler

On the right side of the screen, if it has a value of {611AD258-4138-4348-A534-9856FA6BA398} you need to rename that registry key from 'IconHandler' to something else, IconHandlerX works. Then reboot your PC and the Icons should come back.

Comment: In the case where the IconHandler key doesn't exist?